# How to fix 'expected expression' error when calling a function?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm very new to programming. I wrote a little program (from the CS50 course, week 2) that checks whether a triangle is valid or not.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void valid_triangle(int side[]);

int main(void)
{

    int side[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        side[i]  = get_int("Side %i: ", i+1);
    }
    valid_triangle(side[]);
}

void valid_triangle(int side[])
{
    if (side[0] + side[1] >= side[2] || side[0] + side[2] >= side[1] || side[1] + side[2] >= side[0])
    {
        printf("true\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting 'expected expression' error here (the very last line where I call the function):

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        side[i]  = get_int("Side %i: ", i+1);
    }
    valid_triangle(side[]);
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: remove `[]` in `side[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, you don't need the `[]` when passing `side` to `valid_triangle`. When passing arrays to a function we are not actually passing the entire array to the function but rather telling the function where to find the array. When you write `valid_triangle(side)` you are actually passing a pointer (location in memory) to the first element of the array, the receiving function then knows how/where to access the array based on the variable we passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void valid_triangle(int side[]);

int main(void)
{

    int side[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        side[i]  = get_int("Side %i: ", i+1);
    }
    valid_triangle(side);
}

void valid_triangle(int side[])
{
    if (side[0] + side[1] >= side[2] || side[0] + side[2] >= side[1] || side[1] + side[2] >= side[0])
    {
        printf("true\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor caveat (or major, depending on your point of view).  This may be a semantic detail that is not worth bothering about when first learning the language, or it may be a major error of understanding in the future that can be avoided by understanding the point early.  Arrays are not passed.  Ever.  When you use the name of the array as the argument to a function, the address of the first element of the array is passed.

Comment: Yes you're completely right. I was trying not to confuse the OP with pointer and such and just get the code working. But your right it's probably better be explicit in the learning stages. Ill make an edit.

Comment: @liamcomp, thank you very much for a very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Call your function as `valid_triangle(side);`